# Portfolio gallery without "all" filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a portfolio gallery, I found one on w3schools: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp

My only question is, is it possible to remove the "show all" filter and just have it selected on another filter by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how

1. Remove the 'show all' button
2. Add an `active` css class on the filtering button you want active by default
3. In your JS file, set the `filterSelection` to the current default active button

```js
filterSelection("nature") // Execute the function and show all columns
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Center website */

.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 8px -16px;
}


/* Add padding BETWEEN each column (if you want) */

.row,
.row>.column {
  padding: 8px;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none;
  /* Hide columns by default */
}


/* Clear floats after rows */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Content */

.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */

.show {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Add a dark background color to the active button */

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('nature')"> Nature</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('people')"> People</button>
</div>

<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column nature">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Mountains</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column nature">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/lights.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Lights</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column nature">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Forest</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column cars">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/cars1.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Retro</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column cars">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/cars2.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Fast</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column cars">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/cars3.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Classic</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column people">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/people1.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Girl</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column people">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/people2.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Man</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column people">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="/w3images/people3.jpg" alt="People" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Woman</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END GRID -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove below line of code code:

```
<button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
```

Add to make the next button as active just add class "active" to the next button. For example

```
<button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('nature')"> Nature</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `filterSelection("all")` to `filterSelection("nature")` and add `active` as a class to `<button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('nature')"> Nature</button>`

But in all honestly, if that's your question, then you really need to start learning the basics first, before messing with this.